# Existence of linear functional such that maps finitely many non-zero vectors into non-zero values.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm in trouble in Hoffman&Kunze linear algebra exercise 3.5 problem 14.

The Problem is: $F$ is a field with characteristic zero and let $V$ be finite dimensional vector space over $F$. Given non-zero finitely many vectors $a_i$'s, show we can give a linear functional  $f$ on $V$ s.t. $f(a_i)\neq 0$.

My first approach is find a map explicitly based on basis of $span\{a_i\}$. Just map into each basis into 1. But what if $a_3=a_2-a_1$? It fails if we choose $a_1$ and $a_2$ to basis. We can change mapped value for each basis as $1+1$ but what if vectors are more complicated? In this point of view I think characteristic zero is given to solve this problem.

And my other approch is geometrical thinking. This problem is equivalent to find  dimension of $dim(V)-1$ hyperplane containing zero, and do not containing any of $a_i$'s. Intuitevly I think in this point of view, $F$ is infinite will suffice to show this problem.

In addition, from comments it is also equivalent to union of finitely many subspaces of dimension less by 1 than V cannot be whole V if F is a field of characteristic zero.

Can you give me any hint or solution?

Comment: Your second idea is promising! Hint: impose the standard inner product on $V$, and for each $f\in F$, consider the subspace $W_f$ of all vectors orthogonal to $(f,f^2,\dots,f^{\dim V})$. Can you show that only finitely many of the $W_f$ can contain one of the $a_i$?

Comment: @GregMartin I think your suggestion do not work. Consider $V=\mathbb{R}^3$ and $a_1=(1,0,0)$ then rotation of x-y plane with x-axis will be your $W_v$. Which is infinitely many.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26/can-a-vector-space-over-an-infinite-field-be-a-finite-union-of-proper-subspaces There is an answer.

Comment: I think the case $a_1=(1,0,0)$ works fine with my suggested approach: only one $W_f$ is orthogonal to $a_1$, namely when $f=0$. But, I'm happy you found a satisfactory answer! (You might consider editing the beginning of the problem statement accordingly, for the benefit of future readers.)